# RESTful API data is null in Ionic

Tags: php, ionic2, restful-authentication

I have written following a tutorial some php code to generate a RESTful API endpoint. As a result I get a link to the php file responding the requested data in JSON format. Anyway, it only show the result when I type the URL in browser. If I use it in Ionic, it returns null (no error with header). I've also try other API from a website, and my Ionic codes worked fine with that API.

Can anyone tell me exactly what we need to do to create an API. For example, if header setting is required, then, what headers do we need to set to make sure the API respond data can be accessed from anywhere without authentication.
   Here is my code: 
   ::::api.php

```
`<?php 

require_once("Rest.inc.php");

class API extends REST {

    public $data = "";
    //Enter details of your database
    const DB_SERVER = "localhost";
    const DB_USER = "USER";
    const DB_PASSWORD = "MY_PASSWORD";
    const DB = "MY_DB";

    private $db = NULL;

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();              // Init parent contructor
        $this->dbConnect();                 // Initiate Database connection
    }

    private function dbConnect(){
            $this->db = mysqli_connect(self::DB_SERVER,self::DB_USER,self::DB_PASSWORD,self::DB);
    }

    /*
     * Public method for access api.
     * This method dynmically call the method based on the query string
     *
     */
    public function processApi(){
            $func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("/","",$_REQUEST['rquest'])));
            if((int)method_exists($this,$func) > 0)
                $this->$func();
            else
                $this->response('Error code 404, Page not found',404);   // If the method not exist with in this class, response would be "Page not found".
    }
    private function hello(){
        echo str_replace("this","that","HELLO WORLD!!");

    }


    private function room(){    
        // Cross validation if the request method is GET else it will return "Not Acceptable" status
        if($this->get_request_method() != "GET"){
            $this->response('',406);
        }
        $result_count =  5; 
        if(is_numeric ($this->_request['results'])){
            $result_count = (int)$this->_request['results'];
        }

        $myDatabase= $this->db;// variable to access your database
        $rooms_result = mysqli_query($this->db, "SELECT * FROM rooms ORDER BY RoomID DESC LIMIT $result_count");
        while($room_recordset = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rooms_result)){
            $rooms[] = array('ID' => $room_recordset['RoomID'], 'RoomTitle' => $room_recordset['RoomTitle'], 'RoomSize' => $room_recordset['RoomSize'], 'IsAvailable' => $room_recordset['IsAvailable'], 'Price' => $room_recordset['Price'], 'ParkingLotPrice' => $room_recordset['ParkingLotPrice'], 'ElectricityPrice' => $room_recordset['ElectricityPrice'], 'ContactPhone1' => $room_recordset['ContactPhone1'], 'Description' => $room_recordset['Description'], 'ImageURL' => $room_recordset['ImageURL'], 'RecommendCount' => $room_recordset['RecommendCount'], 'UnrecommendCount' => $room_recordset['UnrecommendCount'], 'CommentCount' => $room_recordset['CommentCount']);    
        }   

        $param = json_encode($rooms);
        $this->response($param, 200);    
    }
}
$api = new API;
$api->processApi();
?>`
```

::::Rest.inc.php

```
<?php
    /* File : Rest.inc.php
    */
    class REST {

        public $_allow = array();
        public $_content_type = "application/json";
        public $_request = array();

        private $_method = "";      
        private $_code = 200;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->inputs();
        }

        public function get_referer(){
            return $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        }

        public function response($data,$status){
            $this->_code = ($status)?$status:200;
            $this->set_headers();
            echo $data;
            exit;
        }

        private function get_status_message(){
            $status = array(
                        100 => 'Continue',  
                        101 => 'Switching Protocols',  
                        200 => 'OK',
                        201 => 'Created',  
                        202 => 'Accepted',  
                        203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information',  
                        204 => 'No Content',  
                        205 => 'Reset Content',  
                        206 => 'Partial Content',  
                        300 => 'Multiple Choices',  
                        301 => 'Moved Permanently',  
                        302 => 'Found',  
                        303 => 'See Other',  
                        304 => 'Not Modified',  
                        305 => 'Use Proxy',  
                        306 => '(Unused)',  
                        307 => 'Temporary Redirect',  
                        400 => 'Bad Request',  
                        401 => 'Unauthorized',  
                        402 => 'Payment Required',  
                        403 => 'Forbidden',  
                        404 => 'Not Found',  
                        405 => 'Method Not Allowed',  
                        406 => 'Not Acceptable',  
                        407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',  
                        408 => 'Request Timeout',  
                        409 => 'Conflict',  
                        410 => 'Gone',  
                        411 => 'Length Required',  
                        412 => 'Precondition Failed',  
                        413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',  
                        414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',  
                        415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',  
                        416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',  
                        417 => 'Expectation Failed',  
                        500 => 'Internal Server Error',  
                        501 => 'Not Implemented',  
                        502 => 'Bad Gateway',  
                        503 => 'Service Unavailable',  
                        504 => 'Gateway Timeout',  
                        505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported');
            return ($status[$this->_code])?$status[$this->_code]:$status[500];
        }

        public function get_request_method(){
            return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        }

        private function inputs(){
            switch($this->get_request_method()){
                case "POST":
                    $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($_POST);
                    break;
                case "GET":
                case "DELETE":
                    $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($_GET);
                    break;
                case "PUT":
                    parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$this->_request);
                    $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($this->_request);
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->response('',406);
                    break;
            }
        }       

        private function cleanInputs($data){
            $clean_input = array();
            if(is_array($data)){
                foreach($data as $k => $v){
                    $clean_input[$k] = $this->cleanInputs($v);
                }
            }else{
                if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
                    $data = trim(stripslashes($data));
                }
                $data = strip_tags($data);
                $clean_input = trim($data);
            }
            return $clean_input;
        }       

        private function set_headers(){
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
            header("HTTP/1.1 ".$this->_code." ".$this->get_status_message());
            header("Content-Type:".$this->_content_type);
            //Note that I've tried remove the below two header, but it 
            //didn't work either.
        }
    }   
?>
```

Comment: Make sure the type of your response is set to json. You might want to use postman to validate if everything is working. Other than that we can't really help you unless you post your code.

Comment: I've already posted, now. Please help me! @AndreasGassmann